# What is the difference when using FIND between -name and -iname

Tags: find

Well the question says it all, I have seen both

```
find -name
```

and

```
find -iname
```

used all over the place without a discernible pattern.

Could somebody explain the differences, perhaps with an example to clarify?

Comment: I asked this question when I was very new to Linux and laugh when I see how popular it is. This question is a perfect example of why you need to learn ASAP how to use `man find` and read the manual. (Or as I would do, google `find flags` and then use search to find the flag in question)

Comment: 10 upvotes and 3 stars is not that "popular" but I am glad you made that comment so I did not have to. (But I am actually here because its faster so search then to scroll to the manual)

Comment: Its nice that the Unix.Linux Community is friendly I feel like this post would get downvoted to Oblivion on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

From the GNU `find` manual page:

```
   -iname pattern
          Like -name, but the match is case insensitive.  For example, the
          patterns `fo*' and `F??' match  the  file  names  `Foo',  `FOO',
          `foo',  `fOo',  etc.
```

Comment: Many tools (and most regular expression interpreters) have case-insensitive options.  Unix/Linux are not hostile to case, they just acknowledge that there is a difference between upper and lower case.

Comment: `-iname` is not part of the standard, but it is supported by various find implementations. So -iname is available in many but not in all cases.